# Problem: failed to create task or type if Cause: The name is undefined

Tags: ant

I am getting the following error report:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2019. Все права защищены.

Buildfile: D:\ForJob\source-archive\apertum-qsystem\build.xml

-pre-init:

-init-private:

-pre-init-libraries:

-init-private-libraries:

-init-libraries:

-init-user:

-init-project:

-init-macrodef-property:

-check-ivy:

-ivy-define:

-ant-contrib-define:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It could not be found.

-lib-path-init:
BUILD FAILED
D:\ForJob\source-archive\apertum-qsystem\nbproject\ivy-impl.xml:40: Problem: failed to create task or type if
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Key line is

- Problem: failed to create task or type **if**

Here is the code associated with the error:

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="${lib.dir}" arg2="$${lib.dir}"/>
    <then>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${build.classes.dir}" arg2="$${build.classes.dir}"/>
            <then>
                <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <property name="lib.dir" value="jar"/>
            </else>
        </if>
    </then>
</if>
```

Comment: <if>
            <equals arg1="${lib.dir}" arg2="$${lib.dir}"/>
            <then>
                <if>
                    <equals arg1="${build.classes.dir}" arg2="$${build.classes.dir}"/>
                    <then>
                        <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <property name="lib.dir" value="jar"/>
                    </else>
                </if>
            </then>
        </if>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask visit this link and ask a proper question with proper wording, indentations of code etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the `if` task from ant-contrib without defining those tasks first. I highly recommend avoiding this task and ant-contrib in general, unless you're doing something that explicitly requires them. Looking at the code snippet you provided, what you're trying to do should be accomplished with native Ant, not these custom tasks.

I'll go through it one step at a time.

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="${lib.dir}" arg2="$${lib.dir}"/>
    <then>
```

Here it looks like you're trying to check if the property `lib.dir` has been assigned a value. This is usually not necessary for reasons I'll explain below, but if you do really need to check this, there's an easier condition to use called `isset`. Like this: `<isset property="lib.dir" />`

```
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${build.classes.dir}" arg2="$${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <then>
```

Same as above, just with a different property.

```
        <then>
            <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="lib.dir" value="jar"/>
        </else>
```

Okay, so you want to set `lib.dir` to "lib" if the classes property is set, or set it to "jar" if it's not. This can ALL be accomplished in the following way, using the `condition` task:

```
<condition name="lib.dir" value="lib" else="jar">
    <isset property="build.classes.dir" />
</condition>
```

You might be wondering where the logic is for first checking whether or not `lib.dir` is set. The answer is that there isn't any, because it would be pointless. Properties in Ant are immutable; once they're set, they cannot be changed. So if `lib.dir` is already holding a value at the time the above code runs, it will keep that original value and this condition task will do nothing.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't help if you actually need to use antcontrib, you solve the OPs issue, but don't answer the question